# Replacing the GPU of my Lenovo M58e type 7306 to GeForce GT 730

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card

Is the GeForce GT 730 compatible with the Lenovo M58e type 730?

Here are the specs: http://support.lenovo.com/en/documents/pd003645#stor

Comment: ANd what's YOUR take on it? What your research tells you?

Comment: I think it's not compatible.

Comment: Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking pity on poor lazy soul and for all future queries along those lines.

Yes, it's possible.

Just look for "half-height nvidia 730 gt".

You can actually put in any one of many GPU cards provided it will not exceed 25W of power consumption (this is max the PCI-e on this system can do) and is half-height card